# I get exception of ULS log of sharepoint when Impersonation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

this is my code:

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINTSYSTEM"].UserToken;
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(oWeb.Site.ID, token))
 {
    using (SPWeb elevatedweb = site.OpenWeb())
     {

     }
 }
```

i run this success. But i see in ULS log of sharepoint, have exceptions as: "Don't dispose object web". I think when i use "using" for proccess, SPSite and SPWeb auto release memory.

Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [SPDisposeCheck rule 120](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_120), [SPSite.OpenWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473155.aspx) should be disposed, so I don't think your error is related to `elevatedweb`. You might want to check other areas of your code. Definitely make sure that `oWeb` isn't being disposed.

Comment: thanks for comment! i think sharepoint don't auto release memory when i pass UserToken for open site. If i don't pass UserToken when open site, i don't get log "Cannot dispose object web" in ULS log sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Use SPDisposeCheck tool to identify if you have memory leaks in this piece of code.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck

Can you please paste the ULS log entry and how you identified it's definitely related to your code?

Your code: is it

`using (SPWeb elevatedweb = site.OpenWeb())` OR

`using (SPWeb elevatedweb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())` ?

Can you please paste the complete piece of code?

Comment: thanks for support!
hi, i find solution for resolve my problem. I have some confusion when release object web, site.